# Sharepoint Column Validation from another list

Tags: validation, validation-list-items

I have a custom list where a user enters information about a vehicle. I want to validate what the user enters as Vehicle ID, against a master Vehicle ID list contained in a seperate custom list.

Is this possible using a validation formula?

Comment: This is not possible OOTB. But you could create the lookup column, so user could have the combo box of all vehicle ids to choose from.

Comment: Why do you want to validate from a separate list? Can you give a better explanation of the business requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damjan has the right answer: create a lookup column. If there are a huge number of vehicle IDs, making a lookup list cumbersome to use, perhaps check out a managed metadata field (which uses its own data store, not a separate list), or get a developer involved to write an event handler.